# Converting BLE service id to UUID(List<int>)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can someone help me convert my BLE service ID to a UUID format... I am using Flutter Reactive BLE plugin for BLE communications in my app.

Here is the service id: 000018AE-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

This needs to be in a List format with the Uuid class of the plugin

```
flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(withServices: [Uuid(...<uuid here>...)], scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency).listen((device) {
      //code for handling results
    }, onError: () {
      //code for handling error
    });
```

Comment: This (000018AE-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB) is UUID. The long one. The short one for this service is 18AE. And this is also UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
`Uuid.parse('000018AE-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB');`

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer please?

Comment: You could convert your service-id to Uuid with Uuid.parse(). Then just add that Uuid to the array.